# Ansible, how to use jinja2 template to access specific value in a list

Tags: ansible, jinja2

New to Jinja2 templating

I can iterate over a list using a for conditional which is simple enough but i am trying to do the below...

I have a variable that contains a un-ordered lists of values which are group names.  I would like to access the group_names lists/variable and check if  a specific item in this list exists and then perform an action if that value is found.

```
   group_names: [ "groupname1", "groupname2", "groupname3", "groupname4"]
```

Comment: Have you tried something yourself already?

Comment: yes.  I tried a if conditional for the value in the list but it  there was no output.    From seeing how i can look at the hostvars debug output, i can see that my test server is not in the group for my condition so it wasn't getting picked up

Comment: thanks for your time,  sorry i didn't think it was that easy

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want:

```
{% if "somevalue" in group_names %}
whatever stuff
{% endif %}
```

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/

Comment: thanks for your valid input.  my dev server was not in the groupname i was running my if condition on and therefore lead to no output.    When i checked the host's group it showed my mistake.